# How to attach mdf database file from other computer

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, database-connection

I am trying to write the vb.net application attaching a `.mdf` file.

The application needs to access mdf file from both local computer and other computer via LAN. According to the situation, I can't use SQL Server. I am required to write the application with the attach the db. So I can able to connect and make processes the application when mdf file is on my pc.

However, I can't able to connect or access db from other computer via LAN.

The connection string I used is

```
Dim conS As New SqlConnection("Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=
D:\Me\Test\mdfAttach\Database\123.mdf;Database=123;Trusted_Connection=Yes;")
```

I can make process with that on my computer

```
Dim conS As New SqlConnection("Server=.\
SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=\\192.168.1.137\Share\mani\123.mdf;Database=123;Trusted_Connection=Yes;")
```

I can't access file from other computer using that connection string

help me guys

Comment: is that mdf file already attached to any other SQL server?

Comment: Computer A -> My Computer (located db)
Computer B -> Other Computer from Lan
A -> can make process
B -> can not access the db